# Applying owner / group recursively in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've a ruby piece of code in Chef that recursively creates some directories

```
 # Deploy config files from files
  unless instance[:directories].nil?
    instance[:directories].each do |dir|
      unless File.directory?("#{dir[:source_dir]}")
        remote_directory "#{dir[:path]}" do
          source "#{dir[:source_dir]}"
          owner "#{config[:owner]}"
          group "#{config[:group]}"
          recursive true
          notifies :run, "execute[change permissions]", :immediately
          notifies :restart, "service[#{instance[:name]}]"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

As per the spec, remote_directory resource applies owner/group permissions only to the leaf node in the path specified but not to the intermediate nodes created.

I plan to notify an execute command when ever a path is created and recursively apply permissions. How do I pass an argument (in this case #{dir[:path]}) to execute command as below.

```
  execute "change permissions" do
    command "chown -R #{config[:owner]}:#{config[:group]} #{path}"
    user "root"
    action :nothing
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. Include the execute resource with your remote directory resource:

```
unless instance[:directories].nil?
    instance[:directories].each do |dir|
      unless File.directory?("#{dir[:source_dir]}")
        path = dir[:path]

        remote_directory path do
          source dir[:source_dir]
          owner config[:owner]
          group config[:group]
          recursive true
          notifies :run, "execute[change-permission-#{path}]", :immediately
          notifies :restart, "service[#{instance[:name]}]"
        end

        execute "change-permission-#{path}" do
          command "chown -R #{config[:owner]}:#{config[:group]} #{path}"
          user "root"
          action :nothing
        end
      end
    end
  end
```